# Empty "Rplot.pdf" file is created every time Rstudio is started

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using Rstudio 1.1.383 and R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) on two different Mac OS X machines.

Every time I start Rstudio or I restart the R session from within Rstudio, an empty file named `Rplot.pdf` is created in the top folder of the current Rstudio project.

I tried re-installing both Rstudio and R with no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is causing the issue is the `effects` package (version 4.0.0). If there is a `.R` file with the line `library(effects)` in the project folder and I open the project, or if I open an `.Rmd` file containing that line from within Rstudio, the plot is created (to be sure, the issue is not happening when loading the package).

I downgraded to a previous version and that seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: I reported the issue to the developer of the package, but he cannot reproduce it.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue on other Mac machines as well.

Comment: I am getting this behavior as well. @Stefano could you link to the issue?

Comment: It was just an email exchange so I can't link to the issue post. I had to upgrade to the latest version of `effects` and having this empty Rplots.pdf everywhere is really annoying.